# How to write a class with attributes of this json file?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have this following json file and I want to instantiate it as an object class to further use this class as a Data Access Object but I'm stuck at the part of defining the class following the json structure. Can anybody please help? Thank you!

Public class Person{

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
private Long id;
private String name;
@Embedded
private List<Information1> Information1;
@Embedded 
private List<Information2> Information2;

public Person(){}
//getters and setters

@Embeddable
@Data
public class Information1 {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String rating;
   

    public Information1(){}

   //getter and setters

    }
 @Data
 @Embeddable
 public class Information2 {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private List<information> information;
    
    public Information2(){}

   //getter and setters

    }
@Data
@Embeddable
public class information{

@Id 
private Long id;
private String key1;
private String key2;
public information(){}

//getters and setters
}
```

}
}

This is the json file structure with some data in.

[image: Json File]

Comment: `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` are annotations used by JPA. See https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable. In your case you would probably need Jackson annotations. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-deserialization-annotations.

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: You must make composition with Jackson Json Serializer/Deserializer annotations, as suggested by @WLefever.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to tell Jackson how to map the fields of your class to the Json elements. The easiest way is to simply annotate the fields with `@JsonProperty`. If the element name does not match the field name, you can also add a mapped name. e.g.

```
@JsonProperty("my_id")
private Long id;
```

Furthermore, inner classes need to be static.

Your Person class could look like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.List;

public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @JsonProperty()
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    
    @Embedded
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Information1> Information1;

    @Embedded
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Information2> Information2;

    //getters and setters

    @Embeddable
    @Data
    public static class Information1 {

        @Id
        @JsonProperty
        private Long id;

        @JsonProperty
        private String name;

        @JsonProperty
        private String rating;

    }

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class Information2 {

        @Id
        @JsonProperty
        private long id;

        @JsonProperty
        private List<Information> information;

        //getter and setters

    }

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class Information {

        @Id
        @JsonProperty
        private Long id;

        @JsonProperty
        private String key1;

        @JsonProperty
        private String key2;

        //getters and setters
    }

}
```

To unmarshall a Json to your Person Object you need a ObjectMapper...

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...
    final String json = ""; // <- Your Json, e.g. as a String
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final Person person = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
...
```

Regards,
Thomas